# Need help about android basic things that confused me for a few days

Tags: android, emulation

I'm a freshman for the android developing, and I met a question that confuse me for a few days.

I run the simple "hello world" code (I promise there is no error in the code, cause I copy it directly from the homepage of SDK), then the emulator runs but my app is not installed in it. and the console is like this:

[2012-06-12 23:05:50 - HelloPig] ------------------------------

[2012-06-12 23:05:50 - HelloPig] Android Launch!

[2012-06-12 23:05:50 - HelloPig] adb is running normally.

[2012-06-12 23:05:50 - HelloPig] Performing com.example.hellopig.HelloPigActivity activity launch

[2012-06-12 23:05:50 - HelloPig] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'aaa'

[2012-06-12 23:05:50 - HelloPig] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'aaa'

[2012-06-12 23:05:55 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

[2012-06-12 23:05:55 - Emulator]

It just keep holding there, I think there should be something like installing app and success. I firstly thought the problem is eclipse cannot find my emulator, but there is no error. I have checked the build debug keystore path, it is the place where my emulator is.
I also have checked the environment variables, but I think there is no problem with them
(I can run java and adb in cmd)

I really have no idea, so could anyone help me?

following are the versions of the softwares:
jdk 1.6
ADT 18.0.0
SDK platform 1.5
eclipes java EE IDE for developers

Looking forward to hearing from anyone of you :)

Comment: The first time the emulator loads it takes forever.  Wait at least ten minutes before giving up.  Also the first time the emulator loads it is screen locked.  You need to swipe to open it.

Comment: Actually it dosen't that long for me. It takes about 1 or 2 minutes to open the emulator, and also I can operate the emulator. But the problem is my app is not installed in it, and the console keep holding there like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting your emulator before trying to install your app.  It looks like you are waiting for Android to start your emulator for you.

Otherwise there isn't enough information here.  I would suggest running logcat (open a command prompt, and type 'adb logcat') which will give you more verbose logging information.

Post the output from your logcat (if your problem isn't immediately obvious).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have checked the logcat and there is nothing. And I think openning the emulator at firet will not work too. Actually I have tried, I opened the emulator at first, then I run my code as android application, then another emulator window appears. This is also a strange thing.

Comment: If another emulator window is starting, the emulator version, and the version of your code are incompatible.  If the running emulator supports the API version of your code, it will automatically be used when you launch.